# How to sum distinct/uniques values among set of multiple duplicates in excel?

Tags: excel, function, duplicates

I thought it will be easy to sum up multiple distinct values among duplicates but when I started to do that I stucked finally. My need is far beyond that is why I need your assistance, please.

The scenario: If a text value is duplicated in a specific range of column A (e.g.), I need to sum all the values of column B (e.g.) that are on the same row as the duplicate entry A and list that value in the row where the "last" (down in the column) duplicate entry is situated each time when a series of duplicates entry appear again.

Example:

```
A:1   Neutral      B:1    0         C:1    1           
A:2   Good         B:2    1         C:2
A:3   Good         B:3    1         C:3    2
A:4   Bad          B:4   -1         C:4     
A:5   Bad          B:5   -1         C:5
A:6   Bad          B:6   -1         C:6   -3
A:7   Good         B:7    1         C:7    1
A:8   Bad          B:8   -1         C:8
A:9   Bad          B:9   -1         C:9   -2
A:10  Good         B:10   1         C:10  
A:11  Good         B:11   1         C:11   2
A:12  Neutral      B:12   0         C:12   1
```

As you can see, Column A has sets of multiple valued duplicates and one valued duplicates:

- “Good” is duplicated 2 times*by 2 values and 1 time* by 1 value;
- “Bad” is duplicated 1 time * by 3 values and 1 time* by 2 values;
- “Neutral” is duplicated  2  times* by 1 value.

I need to sum the values of column B in the rows where the “Neutral” is duplicated in column A ( C:1 answer = 1 and C:12 answer =1), the “Good” in column A ( C:3  answer = 2,  C:7 answer =1, and C:11 answer =2 ) and finally for the “Bad” in Column A (C:6 answer=-3, and C:9 answer = -2 ).

Where in column C?

In addition to the above, I need the formula to write the totals of each changing distinct duplicates in the row of each last unique duplicate number, that is:

```
 1 must be placed in C:1;
 2 must be placed in C:3
 (-)3 must be placed in C:6;
 1 must be placed in C:7; 
 (-)2 must be placed in C:9; 
 2 must be placed in C:11; and 
 1 must be placed in C:12.
```

I think that's it. Thank you all.

Kind regards,
Robin

Comment: Why is `C:1` = `1` when the value in `B:1` = `0`?  Same question for row 12

Comment: Hi guys. I want to thank you all who took a chance to solve my problem. I recieved an exact what I needed from Marcelo Branco - one of excel experts. Below you can see an answer to my problem/ See if this does what you need.
 **Note that i added column headers - they are necessary for the formula work correctly***




 Formula in C2 copied down
 =IF(A2=A3,"",COUNTIF(A2:INDEX(A$1:A1,LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1<>A2),ROW(A$1:A1)-ROW(A$1)+1)),A2)*IF(A2="Bad",-1,1))

 Hope this helps

 M.